# Прочитать из файла в массив слова, состоящие из английских заглавных строчных букв

Tags: c, массивы, файлы

Допустим, имеется символьный файл

Нужно считать все слова из файла и записать их в массив указателей (т. е. чтобы каждое слово было отдельным "столбцом" в массиве указателей)

Разделены слова могут быть чем угодно - пробелом, переносом строки, знаками препинания и т. д.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Решите точно, что такое слово (без точного тз результат хз, а "чем угодно" - это никак не тянет на точное тз). Считывайте файл построчно, разбивайте на слова (например, с помощью `strtok`), добавляйте их в массив. Сам массив придется делать динамическим, так как его размер не известен заранее (или читать файл дважды - первый раз просто чтоб определить количество слов в нем и подготовить соответствующий массив для второго чтения).

Comment: вы хотите только уникальные слова записывать? (словарь создать) Отличаются ли слова в разном регистре? (casefold() реализовать) Могут ли разные слова в разной нормализации быть записаны? (`ёж` и `ёж` — U+451 vs. U+435 U+308) Хотите вообще Unicode поддерживать? (Китайский, русский или только буквы в ascii диапазоне) Какая кодировка у файла? Является ли "2017" или  "" словом? Сколько слов "can't", "cannot", "Салтыков-Щедрин"?

Comment: хочу записывать все слова, а не только уникальные. только английские строчные и заглавные буквы, слова в разном регистре - разные, can't - два слова

Comment: Читайте через `fscanf()`, потом анализируйте на разделители типа кавычек и т.п. Для запоминания выделенных фрагментов можно использовать `strndup()`

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно все слова, включая повторы в память загрузить, то можно сразу весь файл прочитать в одну строку, а в массив сохранить указатели на позиции в этой строке и каждое слово нулевым байтом завершить:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // read file
  char *content = NULL;
  if (argc != 2 || !(content = get_file_contents(argv[1])))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  // find the number of words
  unsigned long words_count = 0;
  bool inword = false;
  for (char *s = content; *s; ++s) {
    if (isalpha(*s)) { // C locale: upper, lower letter
      if (!inword) { // new word
        inword = !inword;
        ++words_count;
      }
    }
    else if (inword) {
      inword = !inword; // end of word
    }
  }

  // put words into array
  char* *words;
  if (words_count > (SIZE_MAX / sizeof *words)
      || !(words = (char**)malloc(words_count * sizeof *words)))
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // let OS cleanup memory

  char *s = content; // rewind
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < words_count; ++i) {
    for ( ; !isalpha(*s); ++s);  // find start of the word
    words[i] = s;
    for ( ; isalpha(*s); ++s);   // find end of the word
    *s = '\0';
  }
  // print words
  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < words_count; ++i) puts(words[i]);
}
```

где

```
/// read file into null-terminated C-string
char* get_file_contents(const char* filename) {
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  unsigned long size;
  char *buf = NULL;

  if((fp = fopen(filename, "rb"))
     && !fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)
     && (size = ftell(fp)) != (unsigned long)EOF   // find file size
     && size < LONG_MAX && size < SIZE_MAX
     && (buf = (char*)malloc(size + 1)) // allocate memory for the content
     && (rewind(fp), 1)
     && fread(buf, sizeof *buf, size, fp) == size  // read the content
     && !fclose(fp)) {
    buf[size] = '\0';
    return buf;
  }

  // error
  if (fp) fclose(fp);
  free(buf);
  return NULL;
}
```

[Полный пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a4604a08d61749e).

Словом считается строка из идущих подряд букв, как определяется [`isalpha()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha)  в "C" локали, то есть латинские большие и маленькие буквы.